# javascript object pattern for a periodically updating object

Tags: javascript

I want to periodically update a js object (after an initialization when the object is created), and was attempting the following:

```
var data = {
    foo: -1,
    bar: -1,
    refresh: function() {
        this.foo = getFoo();
        this.bar = getBar();
    }()
}
```

This doesnt currently work at the moment, the `this` doesnt seem to refer to the data object. There are a few different permutations I could try here - but wondering if i am barking up the wrong tree here? What sort of pattern should I be using for an object that I need to periodically update (called externally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close, ditch those ending `()`:

```
var data = {
    foo: -1,
    bar: -1,
    refresh: function() {
        this.foo = getFoo();
        this.bar = getBar();
    } // <== here
};    // <== Also, semicolon here for best practice
```

Usage:

```
data.refresh();
```

You'll need to provide `getFoo` and `getBar` functions, or accept arguments into `refresh`, e.g.:

```
var data = {
    foo: -1,
    bar: -1,
    refresh: function(newFoo, newBar) {
        this.foo = newFoo;
        this.bar = newBar;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
data.refresh(42, 52);
```

Comment: Great, thanks - and would this be the generally recommended way? using the obj as store for query string vars..

Comment: @flyingcrab: I didn't know that's what you were using it for. Objects are very useful for storing structured information in key/value pairs (that's what they do), so sure. If you need multiple objects that have the same functionality, look at constructor functions, but if you just need one, that's fine. If there's any complexity involved, I'd use named functions instead of anonymous ones (see: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html), but other than that...

Answer (score 1):

`this` will be whatever invokes your function. In your case, you invoke it immediately, automatically, and as such, it'll be invoked by the `window` object.

What you could do is:

```
var data = {
    foo: -1,
    bar: -1,
    refresh: function() {
        this.foo = getFoo();
        this.bar = getBar();
    }
}
data.refresh();
```